# is multiple sitemaps receommendable to a web portal

Tags: php, html, ruby-on-rails, xml, sitemap

I have a cricket based portal check here [cricket scores](http://www.cricandcric.com)
This site has near to millions pages.

But is it advisable to have a multiple sitemaps in the website or not?

if Yes, what Name shall we give for the second site map? sitemap2.xml does this work?

Some where in the blog i have read that each sitemap should not have more than 1000 links, for better indexing, is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a concept of [sitemap indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemap_index): they list all the sitemaps your website has.